# DB2 SQL0255 - Function not supported for query when try to user ROW_NUMBER with JOIN

Tags: sql-server, join, pagination, db2

I am using `[IBM][iSeries Access ODBC Driver][DB2 UDB]` version `V5R4` to query against linked servers. I was getting this error `SQL0255 - Function not supported for query` while I was trying to make add a pagination option to an existing (and working) query.

The original query that was working before I tried to add the pagination is :

```
select *
from openquery(MyLinkedServer,
'
select 
  ORG.FirstName as "First_Name",
  ORG.LastName  AS "Last_Name",
  PRS.Address as Address

  FROM Table1 AS ORG

     inner join Table2 PRS
       ON ORG.Id = PRS.Id 
'
)
```

Next I wanted to add pagination so I modified the code like this:

```
select *
from openquery(MyLinkedServer,
'
select 
  ORG.FirstName as "First_Name",
  ORG.LastName  AS "Last_Name",
  PRS.Address as Address

  FROM
  ( SELECT R . * , ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER ( ) AS ROW_NUM
    FROM Table1 AS R) ORG

     inner join Table2 PRS
       ON ORG.Id = PRS.Id 

 WHERE ROW_NUM BETWEEN 1 AND 10
'
)
```

which is the actual query that gives me the error from the title. In fact the full error is :

```
OLE DB provider "..." for linked server "MyLinkedServer" returned message "[IBM][iSeries Access ODBC Driver][DB2 UDB]SQL0255 - Function not supported for query.".
```

And the final part. If I remove the `JOIN` and leave only the pagination like so:

```
select *
from openquery(MyLinkedServer,
'
select 
  ORG.FirstName as "First_Name",
  ORG.LastName  AS "Last_Name",
  PRS.Address as Address

  FROM Table1 AS ORG

     inner join Table2 PRS
       ON ORG.Id = PRS.Id 
'
)
```

Next I wanted to add pagination so I modified the code like this:

```
select *
from openquery(MyLinkedServer,
'
select 
  ORG.FirstName as "First_Name",
  ORG.LastName  AS "Last_Name"

  FROM
  ( SELECT R . * , ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER ( ) AS ROW_NUM
    FROM Table1 AS R) ORG

 WHERE ROW_NUM BETWEEN 1 AND 10
'
)
```

then the query is working again correctly. So the only think that I can think of is that there's some problem in using `ROW_NUMBER()` together with `JOIN` in the same query in this particular version.

After a lot of research the only thing that I could find out is that each version has it's own specifics on for my particular version I found this:

```
V5R4 supports OLAP. But there are some restrictions described in "SQL Reference".

An OLAP specification is not allowed if the query specifies:
- lateral correlation,
- a sort sequence,
- an operation that requires CCSID conversion,
- a UTF-8 or UTF-16 argument in a CHARACTER_LENGTH, POSITION, or SUBSTRING scalar function,
- a distributed table,
- a table with a read trigger, or
- a logical file built over multiple physical file members.
```

The main thing is to fetch the data so I need to keep the `JOIN` cluase so my question is how can I add pagination to this query for this specific version of `DB2`?

Comment: @ypercube Nope, sorry for the errors, I had to modify the query to keep the original info confidential and it seems that I've missed some things. However I do made all those tests and the result is as described.

Comment: Agreed, point taken!

Comment: Thnx for the correction. I'll delete my (now obsolete) comments.

Comment: I've added a suggestion. Please try it so I can delete.

Comment: Have you run your simplified version and gotten the same errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

v5r4 is quite old, circa 2007, and no longer supported by IBM.

**new info**
At v5r4, IBM was still in the process of moving towards a new SQL Query Engine (SQE) from the original Classic Query engine (CQE).  In order for the new v5r4 OLAP functions to work, the query must be processed by the SQE.

However, certain things could force the system to use the CQE.  Among the most likely.
- mere existence of select/omit logical files
- the use of functions such as UPPER() in the WHERE clause..

You can work around the first problem by setting IGNORE_DERIVED_INDEX=*YES in the query options file "QAQQINI".  Best practice would be to set it in a local copy unless you want to effect every query on the system.
On a command line:

```
CRTDUPOBJ OBJ(QAQQINI)
          FROMLIB(QSYS)
          OBJTYPE(*FILE)
          TOLIB(MYLIB)
          DATA(*YES)
```

You can set the QAQQINI to use on the OLEDB driver connection string (v5r3+).  But it appears you are using ODBC instead.  I'm not sure about v5r4, but the 7.1 ODBC driver allows you to specify "Query options file library"

Unfortunately, there's no work around for the second problem...
If by chance UPPER() or LOWER() are the functions you are using, perhaps for case-insensitive processing; you might be able to create a case-insensitive index and change your sort sequence to *LANGIDSHR.  But you mention that the docs specified that the OLAP functions would work if your query specified a sort sequence.

**end new info**

Been a while since I used it.  The following works on 7.1

```
with tbl as 
  (SELECT 
     ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER ( ) AS ROW_NUM,
     ORG.FirstName as "First_Name",
     ORG.LastName  AS "Last_Name",
     PRS.Address as Address
   FROM ORG
     INNER JOIN PRS
       ON ORG.ID = PRS.ID
)
SELECT * 
FROM TBL
WHERE ROW_NUM BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

Note that without ordering specified, you'll get and unknown set of rows.

I'd suggest you add an window order clause to the row number

```
with tbl as 
  (SELECT 
     ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER (ORDER BY ORG.LASTNAME ) AS ROW_NUM,
     ORG.FirstName as "First_Name",
     ORG.LastName  AS "Last_Name",
     PRS.Address as Address
   FROM ORG
     INNER JOIN PRS
       ON ORG.ID = PRS.ID
)
SELECT * 
FROM TBL
WHERE ROW_NUM BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

Ok, so apparently the above doesn't work on 5.4...Try another layer of CTE

```
with tbl as 
  (SELECT 
     ORG.FirstName as "First_Name",
     ORG.LastName  AS "Last_Name",
     PRS.Address as Address
   FROM ORG
     INNER JOIN PRS
       ON ORG.ID = PRS.ID
)
 , tbl2 as 
(SELECT 
   ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER (ORDER BY "Last_Name" ) AS ROW_NUM,
   , tbl.*
 FROM TBL
)
SELECT * 
FROM TBL2
WHERE ROW_NUM BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

A couple of other techniques...

You could load the results set into a temporary file and then you'd be able to use ROW_NUMBER().

Or you can consider the following:
Basically, lets say you want 10 rows per page and you want page 5 (ie rows 41-50).  The below will give you that.  Performance isn't too bad, initially.  But it does get worse with each page.  You're basically hoping the users don't hit page down 100s of times.  Luckily most won't.

```
select *                              
from (select *                        
      from (select * from mytbl
            order by myfld           
            fetch first 50 rows only  
           ) as t1                    
      order by myfld desc            
      fetch first 10 rows only        
     ) as t2
```

Comment: I got the same exaxt error - `SQL0255 - Function not supported for query."`. However I think to stop trying this since it seems that there's no straigh-forward way to do this. Since you are familiar with this can you tell me, would it be enough to update the driver or the entire OS/DB2 server should be changed to a newer version. I'm pretty unfamiliar with this topic. On my side I'm using `SQL SERVER 2012` and I'm quering Linked servers and I would like also to use `OFFSET` and `FETCH` but don't knwo if this can be done for free?

Comment: Edited the answer to add another layer of CTE.  Try that.  Since the error is coming from the server, you'd have to upgrade the server.  Upgrades to the IBM i are free, if you're current on support & maintenance.  Given that IBM stopped supporting v5r4 a year ago, it's unlikely you're current.

Comment: I've left work several hours ago and I don't have access to the server from other place so I can't try right now the things you suggested. However I think you were very detailed in your explanations and covered most of the topics which one should be aware of when deals with this problem so I'm gonna accept your answer.

Comment: Also, I saw your profile, which explains why you have so much knowledge about those topic. If you feel comfortable I would like to ask you few questions here or in chat. I found some sort of work around by creating a view in my `SQL SERVER 2012` with all the joins and stuff, and then added pagination by querying the view. However this leads to very long execution time - 77 seconds with the pagination. I have no idea where to look for bottlenecks. The query without the pagination took 24 seconds to execute but the person that is taking care for the Linked servers..

Comment: wrote that for him it takes less than a second. I use remote desktop to connect to the server maybe he is accessing it directly but I don't think this matters since at the end we use the same machine to execute the command. The real query itself has 5 joins and each join is with table with 200-300k records but still I think this should be faster. And when I add the view and the pagination the time is ridiculous. Can you suggest me a strategy to try and rework this, and maybe where to look first for potential causes of this huge time consuming process?

Comment: As to your views, if you're doing them directly with a 4 part name, ie: `SELECT * FROM MYLINKEDSER.IBMIDB.MYLIB.ORG` then the way MS SQL Server works is to pull back every row then do the `JOIN` or `WHERE`.  You might try creating the view on the IBM system and going back to the openquery version.